# Parsing JSON errors using simple_form and AJAX in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, forms, simple-form

I have a form that is using Simple Forms and remote => true on the users dashboard (which is handled by a dashboard view and dashboard controller).  The form allows a user to add a custom game rule; however, it's loading the form via a Jquery's .load() function.  The form is loading from the "rules" view (handled by a rules controller).

When the user clicks the submit button, I'm not getting any error validation.

Her is the create action on the rule controller:

```
def create
  @rule = Rule.new(params[:rule])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @rule.save
      format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'Rule was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @rule, status: :created, location: @rule }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render template: 'dashboard/index'}
      format.json { render json: @rule.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

I've got a js file called create.js.erb in my views folder that is currently empty.  I think that I have to somehow parse the JSON error data in this create.js.erb file, but I have no idea how to do it.

Also, does it matter that this form is being called by the Dashboard view/controller but the form is being handled by the Rule controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following inside create.js.erb

```
$('.error-messages').remove();
<% if @rule.errors.any? %>
  $('body').append('<ul class="error-messages"></ul>');
  <% @rule.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    $('.error-messages').append('<%= escape_javascript msg %>');
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will append the errors in your body tag.