# Rails Remote form validation errors not showing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created an ajax form in Rails 4 using remote: true. For some reason that I'm missing, my validation errors are not showing in the form.

Here is my current codebase:

**1. Form**

```
= simple_form_for @foo, url: foos_path, as: :foo, remote: true do |f|

  .row
    .input-field
      = f.input :bar

  .right-align.card-button
    = f.button :submit, class: "waves-light blue", data: { disable_with: "Loading..." }
```

**2. create.js.erb**

```
$("#new_foo").html('<%= j render_cell :foo, :form, foo: @foo %>');
```

**3. Controller**

```
def create
  @foo = FooForm.new( Foo.new )
  respond_to do |format|
    if @foo.validate(params[ :country ])
        @foo.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @foo.model }
        format.js 
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @foo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js 
    end
  end
end
```

I would expect this code to show validation errors after a for being submitted incorrectly. Yet for some reason nothing happens after an incorrect submission. I can confirm that the form is being submitted however since the submission is processed in the log.I can also confirm that the form works perfectly fine when I remove remote submission.

Is there anything that I'm missing?

PS. I am using the [Reform](https://github.com/apotonick/reform) gem which might make my controller object code seem a little bit unfamiliar to a lot of people. I am rendering a cell in my js file as per this [gem](https://github.com/apotonick/cells)

**UPDATE**
I have struggled with this some more. I implemented a solution that I've copied a 'remote: true' solution that I've built in a previous app, verbatim. This worked flawlessly in my previous app but does not display validation errors in my new app. The only difference between these two apps are the version of Ruby and Rails.

In the first app I ran Ruby: 2.2.1 with Rails: 4.2.2. My new app ('the one that I can't get working') I'm running Ruby: 2.2.3 with Rails: 4.2.4.

Could this perhaps have an impact??

Comment: I learnt about `render_cell` from your answer, thank you

Comment: Can you post the exact HTML response coming through the browser? Interesting how it works without being `remote`

Comment: @RichPeck thanks for your response. Glad that I could help. It's a great little gem and it's helped me a lot with with cleaning up my code. I am not clear on what exactly you're asking for? I have updated my question with some more detail as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After many hours I have finally managed to solve this issue. Still not sure why this is happening but I am posing the answer here in case somebody else ever experiences something similar. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126591/js-erb-not-executing-javascript-but-is-processed-rails) Stackoverflow answer led me in the right direction.

I needed to add this line into my create action:

```
format.js    { render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript' }
```

Thus my full create action now looks like this:

```
def create
  @foo = FooForm.new( Foo.new )
  respond_to do |format|
    if @foo.validate(params[ :country ])
        @foo.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @foo.model }
        format.js 
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @foo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js   { render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript' }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: same problem as you bro. I added remote = true and the validations are not showing - i guess it's because the form is not being submitted. do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it doesn't work is because AJAX defaults to expecting parseable javascript as a response, not json objects itself. you need to adjust `$.ajaxSetup` with `dataType: json`, or pass 'json' as a final parameter to $.post (after the callback) so it'll default to anticipating json.

Answer (score 1):

From looking over the code, the only thing I saw that seems even slightly out of sorts - is the render call. Correct me if I'm wrong, but currently wouldn't you be returning the errors as the model object, whereas I think you'd need to provide it with the `errors` key.

`format.json { render json: {errors: @foo.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity }`

Or, additionally I believe if you were to just return the object itself, the errors would be properly mapped to an `errors` key within the object.

`format.json { render json: @foo, status: :unprocessable_entity }`

Comment: Thanks for this attempt @codeurge. Unfortunately still no luck. I can see the correct response in my JS console, but the errors are not displayed in my form.

Comment: I have updated my question with some more detail. I've tried numerous approaches but still no luck.

Comment: Given the additional information that you're able to see the errors in the JS console on a JSON response, and that you see the errors on HTML response (`remote: true` removed) - you may want a second opinion, but I wasn't able to find that simple_form supports rendering of errors returned via AJAX out of the box. You may have to either return the simple_form as a partial in JSON with the errors and re-render that response to the DOM, or write some code to display just the errors returned. I suspect this because you have errors in both cases the only difference between responses is a re-render.

Comment: An example of the above recommendation could be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444473/parsing-json-errors-using-simple-form-and-ajax-in-rails